# Is $\langle k \vert k_1k_2\rangle=0$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, commutator

Using that $$ \vert k_1k_2\rangle  = a^\dagger({\bf k_1})a^\dagger({\bf k_2})\vert 0 \rangle$$ and the commutation relations

$$[a({\bf k}),a^\dagger({\bf k'})]=(2\pi)^32\omega\delta^3(\bf {k}- \bf {k'})$$ 
what would then be for instance 
$$\langle k\vert k_1k_2\rangle=?$$

Comment: Have you tried writing down the bracket with the annihilation/procreation operators in full, and permuted them inside the vacuum state according to the commutator rule?

Comment: Yeah man I get zero because there's always one a or a-dagger left over it seems.

Comment: In other words, a two particle state is orthogonal to a one particle state.

Comment: Yes @Siva but what about a particle decaying into two/multiparticle state?

Comment: In such a case, you'd have a 1-particle state in the _initial_ Fock space and a 2-particle space in the _final_ Fock space and an insertion of the time evolution operator in between them. In the case of an interacing theory with a corresponding trivalent vertex, the evolution operator can indeed cause one particle to decay into two.

Comment: Ur right Siva. I'm too tired

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as

$$\langle k|k_1k_2\rangle = \langle 0| a(\mathbf{k}) a^{\dagger}(\mathbf{k_1}) a^{\dagger}(\mathbf{k_2}) |0\rangle$$

and

$$a(\mathbf{k})a^{\dagger}(\mathbf{k_1}) = a^{\dagger}(\mathbf{k_1})a(\mathbf{k}) + f(\omega)\delta(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k_1})$$

you'll get one term that vanishes because you cannot destroy the vacuum and one term that simply forces those two $\mathbf{k}$'s to be equal. Of course then you'll still left with one $a^{\dagger}$ that you cannot get rid of, which tries to destroy the left vacuum and indeed yields zero.

You can see this result is correct from the mere fact that you have a one-particle state and a two-particle state. Since states with different total number of particles are orthogonal, we can immediately conclude that their inner product must be zero.

Comment: I indeed get zero just as you described. But if this is zero, this means the projection of a single particle state on a multiparticle state is zero: what about a particle decay then? Isn't $\langle k|k_1k_2\rangle \sim \mathcal{T}$ via the LSZ formula? I'm confused right now.

Comment: @LoveLearning Ah, comme ça. I don't want to go into the whole derivation, but you'll probably find [this](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic473482.files/06-LSZ.pdf) helpful to understand the LSZ formula. The maths and the interpretation/explanation are both quite clear in these notes. (perhaps [this](http://physics.indiana.edu/~sg/p622/qft_S5-11.pdf) will also be helpful, although it's pretty similar to those notes)